# Why isn't Python turtle graphics background color changing?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Being new to Python, I've only just started using graphics. I have just watched a tutorial in which the tutor used the "turtle" module.  I am struggling as the background color, nor title appear to be changing, despite my code:

```
#Space Invaders
import turtle
import os

#Set up screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor(33,255,0)
wn.title("Space Invaders")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ... Are you sure you don't get any error?

Answer (score 1):

You should have received the error:

```
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (33, 255, 0)
```

Python turtle has two numeric color modes, integer (0 - 255) and float (0.0 - 1.0).  By default, it uses the floating colormode:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> turtle.colormode()
1.0
>>> help(turtle.colormode)
Help on function colormode in module turtle:

colormode(cmode=None)
    Return the colormode or set it to 1.0 or 255.

    Optional argument:
    cmode -- one of the values 1.0 or 255

    r, g, b values of colortriples have to be in range 0..cmode.

    Example:
    >>> colormode()
    1.0
    >>> colormode(255)
    >>> pencolor(240,160,80)

>>>
```

You have to explicitly request the integer one:

```
# Space Invaders
import turtle

# Set up screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.colormode(255)
wn.bgcolor(33, 255, 0)
wn.title("Space Invaders")

wn.mainloop()
```

You need to end with `mainloop()`, or one of its variants (`done()`, `exitonclick()`), to turn control over to tkinter's event loop to keep the window open.  Otherwise it will fall off the end of the script and close.